# dynamically show sum of tow columns in third column of table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, and have been stucked in a problem....
want to display some calculation of two columns of a table in third coluns dynamically...i.e. suppose when user types 10 and 20 in two columns then third column should be dynamically filled as 200(for example).

please suggest me how can I achieve this in angularjs.

I am using ng-repeat to populate simple table in HTML.
HTML code is

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">S.No.</th>
                                                            <th class="col-sm-5" style="text-align:center">Certificate Name</th>
                                                            <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">No of New Certificate</th>
                                                            <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">No of Duplicate Certificate</th>
                                                            <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">Transcript Amount</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr ng-repeat="payment in TRAN_PaymentDetail">
                                                            <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">{{$index+1}}
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="col-sm-5">
                                                                <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" ng-model="payment.Title" required />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="col-sm-1">
                                                                <input type="number" min="0" name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.NoofNewCertificate" />
                                                            </td> 
                                                            <td class="col-sm-1">
                                                                <input type="number" min="0" name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.NoofDuplicateCertificate" />
                                                            </td>  
                                                            <td class="col-sm-1">
                                                                <input type="text" readonly name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.HeadAmount" value="{{CalulateHeadAmount()}}" />
                                                            </td>                                                              
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
```

I want to show HeadAmount on the basis of NoofNewCertificate and NoofDuplicateCertificate. As soon as user enters these values HeadAcount should dynamically filled.

Thanks in Advance
Regards,

Comment: you can look to my answer.. hope that works for you. Let me know does this solve your problem or required something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.Data = [{ "Col1": 1, "Col2": 1 }];


});


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">S.No.</th>

                <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">Col 1</th>
                <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">Col 2</th>
                <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">Sum</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="payment in Data">
                <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">
                    {{$index+1}}
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" min="0"  class="form-control" ng-model="payment.Col1" required />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.Col2" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.Col1 + payment.Col2" />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of promoting your Youtube channel, you could instead give an answer, just saying. And a filter isn't necessary at all, if I understood his question correctly.

Comment: I was not promoting my video channel, i was just helping him. Though i have deleted.

Comment: Man, we can see what you edited. It's okay, you won't get banned, I won't report you either, but I'm just saying that you must avoid this kind of "help".

Comment: Thanks  Chandra Prakash Variyani.....
got the trick and now able to show calculated value in the cell of table

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="payment in TRAN_PaymentDetail">
        <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center">{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" ng-model="payment.Title" required />
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="number" min="0" name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.NoofNewCertificate" />
        </td> 
        <td class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="number" min="0" name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.NoofDuplicateCertificate" />
        </td>  
        <td class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" readonly name="NewTranscript" class="form-control" ng-model="payment.HeadAmount" ng-value="payment.NoofNewCertificate * 1 + payment.NoofDuplicateCertificate * 1" />
        </td>                                                              
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Assuming that your 2 inputs are the values entered by the user, and the last one is the addition of the two.

Comment: Thanks trichetriche for your suggestion...
I tried ng-value as well it worked also.
but used ng-change on cells to compute the desired value and using ng-model to bind the value to show in the view.

once again thanks..

Comment: No problem, remember to mark a valid answer as verified to help people who will have the same problem as you.